# Am trying to get user details base on his username and password using axios

Tags: javascript, axios

When I use the first username and password which is available in the database it work correctly. But when I try another username and password it does not work. Only for the first row actually work

I have try to search to see how to do it but cannot find a solution. I did not put any validation for the form as I wanted to see it work first

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

  const actualData = {
    userName: data.get("userName"),
    password: data.get("password"),
  };

  if (actualData.userName && actualData.password) {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/loginAdmin/", { params: actualData })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  } else {
  }
};
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your backend code

Comment: _"it does not work"_... how does it not work? What does your logging show?

Comment: FYI sending credentials over a GET request is a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: for the first user in the database if i use his username and password , it show all the details, all the other when i try, it show an empty object

Comment: If it responds with a successful status but empty data, then the problem is definitely in the backend.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Oh yes I found it, it was the sql query that was not correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).